# Java - Riot API

Tags: java, riot-games-api

I am using the RIOT Games APi and using the example code that is provided however the console displays:

```
net.rithms.riot.dto.Game.RecentGames@35d176f7
```

I'm not so sure, I wrote a different code that requests user ID which works perfectly fine.

```
import net.rithms.riot.constant.Region;
import net.rithms.riot.constant.Season;
import net.rithms.riot.api.RiotApi;
import net.rithms.riot.api.RiotApiException;
import net.rithms.riot.dto.Game.RecentGames;

public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) throws RiotApiException {

        RiotApi api = new RiotApi("KEY", Region.EUW);
        api.setSeason(Season.CURRENT);

        RecentGames recentGames = api.getRecentGames(api.getSummonerByName("Vodkamir Putkin").getId());

        System.out.println(recentGames);
    }
}
```

Not sure what that means or what to do with it, according to the API it should display information about my recent Games

Comment: you got the recentGames object, now you can access properties of it. for example; recentGames.getName(); if there is name property.

Comment: Do you really think posting your api key on a public accessible site is a good idea?

Comment: I looked at the docs that has a a single method that can be called getGames() but once I call that method it just brings up more similar previous console outputs. I want access details of those outputs

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(recentGames);`

That will implicitly call the [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method on the `recentGames` object. Unless the `RecentGames` class overrides the `toString()` method, according to the documentation linked above, it will effectively print:

> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

I'm not familiar with the RIOT API, but if you want to get more specific information, your best bet is to take a look at what other methods you can call on the `RecentGames` object.

---

Edit:

As long as you keep calling methods that return objects which don't override `toString()`, you'll keep running into the same problem.

[`System.out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) object. Take some time to look at the documentation, specifically to `print(...)` and `println(...)` methods.

If you pass in something that is an `int`, for example, you're calling the `print(int)` or `println(int)` method. If you pass in a `String`, you're calling the `print(String)` or `println(String)` method. If you pass in a primitive, you are calling the corresponding method. If you pass in any other `Object`, you are effectively doing this:

```
Object myObject;
String myObjectAsAString = myObject.toString(); // See above for what this evaluates to
                                                // if the class doesn't override toString()
System.out.println(myObjectAsAString);
```

If you really want to print out meaningful information, you have two options:

1. Keeping calling methods on the objects until you hopefully get to a class that has methods which return a `String` or primitive that can be printed out, or overrides `toString()`.
2. Write some logic to interpret the results of the methods you're calling. For example, instead of `System.out.println(recentGames.getGames());`, you can check if `recentGames.getGames().isEmpty()` and print `No recent games`, or something like that.

Comment: I looked at the docs that has a a single method that can be called getGames() but once I call that method it just brings up more similar previous console outputs. I want access details of those outputs

Comment: @Dani Was the edit helpful? Are you still having issues?